# Add linetype to geom_segment legend

Tags: ggplot2, legend, legend-properties, geom-segment

**Aim**: add the linetypes of the segments to the legend, as well as the colour.

**Problem**: only the colour is showing.

**Data**:

`m = as.data.frame(matrix(c(1:10), ncol = 2, nrow = 10))`

**Plot**:

`ggplot(m, aes(v1,v2)) + geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 9.75, y = 10, yend = 10, colour = "PEL"), linetype = "dotted") + geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 9.75, y = 5, yend = 5, colour = "AL1"), linetype = "longdash") + geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 9.75, y = 2, yend = 2, colour = "ISQG"), linetype = "solid") + scale_colour_manual("legend", values = c("PEL" = "black", "AL1" = "blue", "ISQG" = "purple"), guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1))) + theme(legend.position = "bottom")`

I've tried adding `scale_linetype_manual(values = c("PEL" = "dotted", "AL1" = "longdash", "ISQG" = "solid")` but nothing changes.

This answer is similar, [Legend linetype in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54245305/12313457) but I couldn't figure out how to make it work with `geom_segment`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

The most ggplot-esque way of doing this, is to include a linetype variable as part of mapping in the `aes()` functions. You must then ensure that both the linetype and colour scales have the same titles, breaks, limits, labels etc.

Alternatively, you can also include the linetype in the `override.aes` part of `guide_legend()`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = 0, xend = 9.75, y = 10, yend = 10, colour = "PEL", linetype ="PEL"), 
  ) + 
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = 0, xend = 9.75, y = 5, yend = 5, colour = "AL1", linetype ="AL1"), 
  ) + 
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = 0, xend = 9.75, y = 2, yend = 2, colour = "ISQG", linetype = "ISQG"), 
  ) + 
  scale_colour_manual(
    "legend", 
    values = c("PEL" = "black", "AL1" = "blue", "ISQG" = "purple"), 
  ) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(
    "legend", 
    values = c("PEL" = "dotted", "AL1" = "longdash", "ISQG" = "solid"), 
  ) + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly :) I'm unable to vote though